# How to delete a row in cql based on Set<text> content

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I have a Cassandra table and one column is defined as `Set<text>`. I want to delete rows that contain specific elements in that set.

For example if the table had a column `names` contained random values like `["Alice","Bob","Eve"]`,
I want a command to delete all the rows that contain the word `Eve`.

If `name`was of type `text` then the command would go something like:

`delete from keyspace.table where name='Eve';`

however that does not work since `name` is not text but `Set<text>`. What would be an equivalent command here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete from keyspace.table where name CONTAINS 'Eve';`

however you need to have secondary index on name column.